# Deriving the distribution of Random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am reading a paper here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7564878

As explained in the following, I cant understand how Eq. 2 is derived by the authors.

$P_I$ is a random variable (Received Power in full-duplex transciever model) and the randomness in $P_I$ is because of random fading power $g = |h|^2$. $P_I$ is given as:

$$P_I = P_T \kappa d^{-\alpha}g$$

$\kappa$, $\alpha$ are constants and $g = |h|^2$. In the following, I cant understand how the authors have come up with Eq. 2.

I will appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a r.v. $X\sim\text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and it is required to find the density function for $Y=c\,X^2$, where $c$ is a positive constant.

$$\begin{align}P(Y\le y)&=P(cX^2\le y)\\[2ex]
&=P(X^2\le {y\over c})\\[2ex]
&=P\left(-\sqrt{y\over c}\le X\le\sqrt{y\over c}\right)\\[2ex]
&=F_X\left(\sqrt{y\over c}\right)-F_X\left(-\sqrt{y\over c}\right)
\end{align}$$
Differentiating to get the densities ...
$$\begin{align}f_Y(y)&={f_X\left(\sqrt{y\over c}\right)\color{blue}{+f_X\left(-\sqrt{y\over c}\right)}\over 2c\sqrt{y\over c}}.\\
\end{align}$$

The portion in blue has been omitted in Equation (2), which is possibly justified by the approximations they are making. In particular, they state that $K$ is "large", which suggests that $v^2$ is only slightly less than $1$, and hence that the variance of the normal distribution is very small. This implies that the distribution of $h$ is very concentrated near the value of $1$, in which case the omitted portion of the density function might be negligible.

---

**Numerical cross-checks**:

Technically, Equation (2) fails to describe a probability density function, because of the mentioned omission. Thus, choosing $\tau>0$ and $0<v<1$, we find, for  $f_{P_I}$ given by Equation (2): $$\int_0^\infty f_{P_I}(x)dx \neq 1,$$
although the discrepancy decreases as $v$ increases toward $1.$

Pasting the following into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to integrate Equation (2) yields a value less than $1$:

```
tau=1; v=1/2; integrate (1/(2 sqrt(pi tau x (1-v^2)))) exp(-(sqrt(x/tau)-v)^2/(1-v^2)) dx from x=0 to oo
```

Pasting the following into Wolfram Alpha to integrate the "corrected" version yields exactly $1$:

```
tau=1; v=1/2; integrate (1/(2 sqrt(pi tau x (1-v^2)))) (exp(-(sqrt(x/tau)-v)^2/(1-v^2)) +  exp(-(-sqrt(x/tau)-v)^2/(1-v^2)) )  dx from x=0 to oo
```

Numerical trials suggest that if $0.9\le v < 1$, then Equation (2) integrates to at least $0.998$.

Comment: What is non-monotonicity here?

Comment: I think the authors must have removed the BLUE part that you have because this is F_X(-\sqrt{\frac{y}{c}}) would be Zero? The reason I say this is because the $X$ here represents the channel here. What do you say?

Comment: @Sjaffry At first I thought something like that might be happening, but then I tried specific numerical cases and found the discrepancy too great. (See the cross-check in my edit.)

Comment: @Sjaffry I just noticed the assumption that $K$ is "large", which implies that $v^2$ should be only "slightly" less than $1$ (hence the variance of the normal distribution is very small). In such case, it may  be that the discrepancy is negligible after all.